# Android firebase retrieve Authenticated user information

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making an android app where people can login and register and they will have a profile containing all of their information such as their first name,last name,email. I am using Firebase so I can build this app. The problem I am having is I am trying to retrieve the Authenticated user information from the Firebase database such as their first name or last name, but I don't see how to pull that out. I'm only able to get there email or phone number or profile photo. below is my code.

```
 //Register.java
       fname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_name);
    lname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_last_name);
    email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.signupemail);
    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.signuppassword);

    signinbutton=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.have_an_account_button);
    signupbutton=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.signupbutton1);

    firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("businessowners");

    signupbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final String txt_firstname=fname.getText().toString();
            final String txt_lastname=lname.getText().toString();
            final String txt_email=email.getText().toString();
            final String txt_password=password.getText().toString();

            if(txt_firstname.isEmpty() ){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Name required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }



            if(txt_email.isEmpty()){

                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Email required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            if(txt_password.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }



            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(txt_email,txt_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                       businessowners information=new businessowners(

                                txt_firstname,
                                txt_lastname,
                                txt_email
                        );

                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("businessowners").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                .setValue(information).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Registration successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                Intent inty=new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                                startActivity(inty);
                            }
                        });

                    }else if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException){

                      email.setError("Email exist");
                      email.requestFocus();

                    }
                }
            });


        }
    });


 //Profile.java
txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_email);
    txt1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_firstname);

    signoutbtn=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.signout);

    firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user");

    String UID=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();


    FirebaseUser firebaseUser=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    //Get users email
    String user_info1=firebaseUser.getEmail();

    //display users email
    txt.setText(user_info1);







    signoutbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            finish();
            Intent inty=new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(inty);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Show us how you authenticate the user.

Comment: @AlexMamo what do you mean? They have to register first and then I pull out their information from the firebase database. I have one example above like their email.

Comment: Show us that code.

Comment: @AlexMamo I just edited my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem I am having is I am trying to retrieve the Authenticated user information from the Firebase database such as their first name or last name

The problem is that you are trying to get the first name and last name from the `FirebaseUser` object which does **not** contain that information. In the following line of code:

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(txt_email,txt_password)
```

You are passing to the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method **only** the `txt_email` and `txt_password` and that's why only that data is available. If you want to get all the data, you need to get it from the database because all that data exists only there. The following code will do the trick:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("businessowners").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String txt_firstname = dataSnapshot.child("txt_firstname").getValue(String.class);
        String txt_lastname = dataSnapshot.child("txt_lastname").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, txt_firstname + " " + txt_lastname);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in the logcat will be the first and the last name of the authenticated user.

Comment: Thank you for that information. but I how do I display the first and last name in the profile activity page? For example set the text to users first name? I don't want to output the name in the logcat I want to actually display it on their profile so they can see the information they provided when they signed up

Comment: The simplest solution would be to find your views and set the text in the `onDataChange()` method. `firstNameTextView.setText(txt_firstname);`. Does it work?

Comment: YESSSSS!!! it works OMG you're the man thank you. I've been stressing about this for a while now. Thank you so much it works like charm